# Cause of TransactionTooLargeException?

Tags: android, runtime-error

I'm trying to fill a ListView in a fragment using my own custom adapter and I seem to only be getting this exception when I select the tab at runtime. What is the main thing causing this exception to be thrown when I click on my events tab?

Here is the MyAdapter class

```
package com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.events_past_list_item, values);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.events_past_list_item,parent,false);
    String itemTitle = getItem(position);
    TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    theTextView.setText(itemTitle);

    ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_events);
    return theView;
}
}
```

Here is the EventsPast class

```
package com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class EventsPast extends Fragment {


public EventsPast() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events_past, container, true);
    String[] fakeData = {"Donald Trump is running for president","Twins trade for Clayton Kershaw",
    "Derek Banas's Android Tutorial Series Helped Me Make This","This is some more fake news"};
    ListView listView = (ListView) theView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_events_past_list_view);
    ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),fakeData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return theView;
}

}
```

Here are the xml files
fragment_events_past.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EventsPast">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_events_past_list_view"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

events_past_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_events"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Error Messages

07-30 16:38:14.888 22018-22018/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                             at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:11749)
                                                                             at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11711)
                                                                             at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:15845)
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:367)
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.jumpToCurrentState(RippleDrawable.java:221)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(AbsListView.java:2974)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(FrameLayout.java:224)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5848)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGrou
07-30 16:38:14.898 22018-22053/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 41(3024B) AllocSpace objects, 1(22MB) LOS objects, 14% free, 92MB/108MB, paused 1.953ms total 215.717ms
07-30 16:38:14.908 22018-22018/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
07-30 16:38:14.908 22018-22018/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 19877752
07-30 16:38:14.908 22018-22018/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:504)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4179)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:118)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-30 16:38:14.908 22018-22018/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround D/Process: killProcess, pid=22018
07-30 16:38:14.918 22018-22018/com.lucasmikesoftware.messaround D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:138 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690

Comment: Please add the stacktrace so we can see the cause of the exception

Answer (score 0):

When inflating your layout in `EventsPast.onCreateView` with the line

```
View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events_past, container, true);
```

the third parameter, `boolean attachToRoot`, should be `false`. You should not attach the newly inflated layout to the root (which is `container` in this case) on inflation because the `Fragment` is designed to do this after you return `theView` as is required by `onCreateView`.

It was able to get your code to work with this modification.